# How to open project in XCode which is created in IBM Cloud Application Tools?

Tags: swift, xcode, ibm-cloud

I have created Project using IBM Cloud Application Tools and now I am unable to open in xcode. When I am trying to open it wasn't. How I can open it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the file extension for the project file?  `.xcodeproj` or `.xcworkspace` or?

Comment: I have created Kitura-Starter sample project and it cloning the repository. https://developer.ibm.com/swift/#quick-start  I have gone through this.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Does the project file have a file extension that Xcode will recognize?  According to [this screenshot](https://developer.ibm.com/swift/wp-content/uploads/sites/69/2016/11/LaunchBrowser.png) from the [Use IBM Cloud Tools For Swift](https://developer.ibm.com/swift/#ci) section of this documentation, you should have a local project file that ends in `.xcodeproj` (and that's openable in Xcode).

Comment: I didn't see any file extension with .xcodeproj and .xcworkspace. in local project file.

Comment: Actually I am iOS App Developer and I'm new to IBM Cloud Application Tools and when I am cloning the project in local I didn't see any file with extension of .xcodeproj and .xcworkspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate an Xcode `.xcodeproj`.

Here are the steps:

- Go to your project directory where you have your **Package.swift** file
- Run:

  `swift package generate-xcodeproj`
- Open the generated project in Xcode.
- Change the build scheme to your executable. Xcode defaults to the module of the same name, which won’t run.
- Run.

> More information in the [official docs](http://www.kitura.io/en/starter/xcode.html).